# how to show a view in controller using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-blade

is it possible in Laravel to show a view within a Controller function without stopping that functions logic/process?

What I mean is, when I access this specific route (via. GET Method), the user is presented with a blank white screen for about 10 seconds while a good amount of logic is ran before redirecting to a new view. How can I show a view while that logic runs?

**EXAMPLE:**

```
protected function callback(Request $request)
{
  // - LOGIC DONE HERE WHICH CALLS ABOUT 3 SUBSEQUENT FUNCS, WHICH 
  // TAKES LONGER THAN USUSAL

  // - I WANT TO RETURN A VIEW HERE IN THE MEANTIME WHILE LOGIC RUNS 
  // WITHOUT HALTING THE PROCESS SO USER WONT BE SUBJECT TO JUST PLAIN 
  // WHITE SCREEN FOR EXTENDED PERIOD OF TIME
}
```

How would I go about doing so?

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible, due to how server/client/requests works. Perhaps you can solve it like this. Have only ONE view, with a default loader HTML element, something like a spinner gif. Then you put something like this piece of JS to run as soon as your page is loaded

```
fetch('/api/your-logic-process')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then(function(data) {
      //hide the loading element 
      //render the results
  })
```

This assumes you have an API route `/api/your-logic-process` where you can handle your time consuming tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Once you responded **the blank page** then the [**PHP** request is dead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/lifecycle). It must involves some sort of front-end mechanism in order to achieve what you want.

For example, using [AJAX](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/laravel/laravel_ajax.htm).

```
// HomeController
public function index() {
  return view('home');
}

// home.blade.php
function getMessage() {
  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'/getmsg',
    data:'_token = {{ csrf_token() }}',
    success:function(data) {
        $("#msg").html(data.msg);
    }
  }); 
}
$(document).ready(function () {
  getMessage();
}
```

If you need to process a task that takes a long time(let's say few minute) and you don't want user to wait for the response, you can use [Queue](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues) and [broadcast](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting) to front-end and return the view to ask user to wait first.

```
// HomeController
public function index() {
  MailJob::dispatch();

  return view('home');
}

// MailJob
public function handle() {
  // job logic
  broadcast(new MailSent); // Notify front-end the event
}
```

Then the `MailSent` event will be broadcasted to front-end. You then listen to the event using the `Laravel Echo` in your frontend.

These **Queue** and **Broadcast** requires quite some time to setup if you're not familiar. Use it wisely.